# All the customers who have spend more than 1200

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum, having-clause

I need to write a query where on this table

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    OrderID INT,
    OrderDate DATE,
    OrderPrice INT,
    OrderQuantity INT,
    customerName VARCHAR(20)
);
```

This is my table right now

```
+---------+------------+------------+---------------+--------------+
| OrderID | OrderDate  | OrderPrice | OrderQuantity | customerName |
+---------+------------+------------+---------------+--------------+
|       1 | 2005-12-22 |        160 |             2 | Smith        |
|       2 | 2005-08-10 |        190 |             2 | Johason      |
|       3 | 2005-07-13 |        500 |             5 | Baldwin      |
|       4 | 2005-07-15 |        420 |             2 | Smith        |
|       5 | 2005-12-22 |       1000 |             4 | Wood         |
|       6 | 2005-10-02 |        820 |             4 | Smith        |
|       7 | 2005-11-03 |       2000 |             2 | Baldwin      |
+---------+------------+------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Where I need to get the ***names of all the unique customers who have spent more than 1200***

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation and `having`:

```
select customerName
from sales
group by customerName
having sum(orderPrice) > 1200
```